# .each function causes appending issue

Tags: jquery, each

I am attempting to read through a list of given input names, and then check for those input names in DIV of span names. Using the below code causes issues with replication..

```
$('.right').find(':input').each(function(){
       $(this).change(function(){
       var class_name ='';
       class_name = $(this).attr('name');  

       $('#specs').find('span').each(function(){ 

       if(class_name == $(this).attr('name')){
       //Update the current span with the information from input.

       }else{
       //Add span with class information  
       $('#specs').append("<span name='"+class_name+"'>"+class_name+"</span>");

       }

       });
  });
```

});

What seems to happening is every time a span gets added the next span added is added + the previous spans.

so...

If you already have 5 spans when you click the next input field you get 11 spans added.... instead of just the one.

Why is this happening?

Any help would be great!

Comment: You have a nested `.each()`. Can you post the HTML or create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$('.right :input').on('change', function() {
    if ( $('span[name="'+ this.name +'"]').length ) { // span already exists
        $('span[name="'+ this.name +'"]').text(this.value);
    } else {
        var span = $('<span />', {name:this.name, text:this.value});
        $('#specs').append(span);
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you! I have been scratching my head all day!

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).change(function(){`

should be `$('.right :input').change(function(){`

And you should remove

`$('.right').find(':input').each(function(){` all together.